# insert data into table using jquery by reading data from url which returns json

Tags: jquery, getjson

Below is my JSON data which i am getting with URL(http://localhost:3000/data)

```
 [{"emp_id":5,"emp_city":"Hyderabad","emp_name":"Sam","emp_phone":"9999999999","emp_sal":"406000"},{"emp_id":1,"emp_city":"Hyderabad","emp_name":"ram","emp_phone":"9999999999","emp_sal":"50000"},{"emp_id":2,"emp_city":"Hyderabad","emp_name":"robin","emp_phone":"9999999999","emp_sal":"406000"},{"emp_id":4,"emp_city":"Hyderabad","emp_name":"krish","emp_phone":"9999999999","emp_sal":"406000"},{"emp_id":6,"emp_city":"Banglore","emp_name":"Bobby","emp_phone":"9999999999","emp_sal":"516000"},{"emp_id":3,"emp_city":"Chennai","emp_name":"rahman","emp_phone":"9999999999","emp_sal":"45000"}]
```

Below is the jquery script i tried to push data to table from above JSON

```
 (function() {
    // Create the connector object
    var myConnector = tableau.makeConnector();

    // Define the schema
    myConnector.getSchema = function(schemaCallback) {
        var cols = [{
            id: "emp_id",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.int
        }, {
            id: "emp_city",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string
        }, {
            id: "emp_name",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string
        }];

        var tableSchema = {
            id: "emp",
            alias:"test",
            columns: cols
        };

        schemaCallback([tableSchema]);
    };

    // Download the data
    myConnector.getData = function(table, doneCallback) {
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/data", function(resp) {
            var feat = resp.features,
                tableData = [];

            // Iterate over the JSON object
            for (var i = 0, len = feat.length; i < len; i++) {
                tableData.push({
                    "emp_id": feat[i].emp_id,
                    "emp_city": feat[i].emp_city,
                    "emp_name": feat[i].emp_name,

                });
            }

            table.appendRows(tableData);
            doneCallback();
        });
    };

    tableau.registerConnector(myConnector);

    // Create event listeners for when the user submits the form
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submitButton").click(function() {
            tableau.connectionName = "Employee Details"; // This will be the data source name in Tableau
            tableau.submit(); // This sends the connector object to Tableau
        });
    });
  })();
```

Below is the error i am getting
The WDC reported an error:
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined stack:TypeError: 
 Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at Object.success 
 (http://localhost:8888/Examples/js/earthquakeUSGS.js:34:39) at j

Please help to fix it.

Comment: There is no property `features` in response data... it is an array unless the json shown is incomplete. Therefore `feat` is undefined and has no `length`

Comment: I am new to jQuery can you please help me to read into table.

Comment: Try `var feat = resp`

Comment: Charlie thanks alot and stack overflow is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
var feat = resp.features,
                tableData = [];
```

There is no `features` property.